# SAS transpose using values as column names and summarize

Tags: sas, transpose

I'm trying to transpose a data using values as variable names and summarize numeric data by group, I tried with proc transpose and with proc report (across) but I can't do this, the unique way that I know to do this is with data set (if else and sum but the changes aren't dynamically)

For example I have this data set:

```
school name   subject      picked  saving   expenses
raget  John   math         10      10500    3500
raget  John   spanish      5       1200     2000
raget  Ruby   nosubject    10      5000     1000
raget  Ruby   nosubject    2       3000      0
raget  Ruby   math         3       2000     500
raget  peter  geography    2       1000      0
raget  noname nosubject    0        0       1200
```

and I need this in 1 line, sum of  'picked' by the names of students, and later sum of picked by subject, the last 3 columns is the sum total for picked, saving and expense:

```
school john ruby peter noname math spanish geography nosubject  picked saving expenses 
raget   15   15   2      0     13   5        2         12        32     22700  8200
```

If it's possible to be dynamically changed if I have a new student in the school or subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult because you're summarising at more than one level, so I've used `PROC SUMMARY` and chosen different `_TYPE_` values. See below:

```
data have;
  infile datalines;  
  input school $ name $ subject : $10. picked saving expenses;
  datalines;
raget  John   math         10      10500    3500
raget  John   spanish      5       1200     2000
raget  Ruby   nosubject    10      5000     1000
raget  Ruby   nosubject    2       3000      0
raget  Ruby   math         3       2000     500
raget  peter  geography    2       1000      0
raget  noname nosubject    0        0       1200
;
run;

proc summary data=have;
  class school name subject;
  var picked saving expenses;
  output out=want1 sum(picked)=picked sum(saving)=saving sum(expenses)=expenses;
run;

proc transpose data=want1 (where=(_type_=5)) out=subs (where=(_NAME_='picked'));
  by school;
  id subject;
run;

proc transpose data=want1 (where=(_type_=6)) out=names (where=(_NAME_='picked'));
  by school;
  id name;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want (drop=_TYPE_ _FREQ_ name subject) as
  select
  n.*,
  s.*,
  w.*
  from want1 (where=(_TYPE_=4)) w,
  names (drop=_NAME_) n,
  subs (drop=_NAME_) s
  where w.school = n.school
  and w.school = s.school;
quit;
```

I've also tested this code by adding new schools, names and subjects and they do appear in the final table. You'll note that I haven't hardcoded anything (e.g. no reference to `math` or `John`), so the code is dynamic enough.

Answer (score 1):

PROC REPORT is an interesting alternative, particularly if you want the printed output rather than as a dataset.  You can use `ODS OUTPUT` to get the output dataset, but it's messy as the variable names aren't defined for some reason (they're "*C2*" etc.).  The printed output of this one is a little messy also as the header rows don't line up, but that can be fixed with some finagling if that's desired.

```
data have;
input school $ name   $ subject      $ picked  saving   expenses;
datalines;
raget  John   math         10      10500    3500
raget  John   spanish      5       1200     2000
raget  Ruby   nosubject    10      5000     1000
raget  Ruby   nosubject    2       3000      0
raget  Ruby   math         3       2000     500
raget  peter  geography    2       1000      0
raget  noname nosubject    0        0       1200
;;;;
run;

ods output report=want;
proc report nowd data=have;
columns school (name subject),(picked) picked=picked2 saving expenses;
define picked/analysis sum ' ';
define picked2/analysis sum;
define saving/analysis sum ;
define expenses/analysis sum;
define name/across;
define subject/across;
define school/group;
run;
```